# XMLHttpRequest Methods not working with jquery plugin in IndexedDB

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

In my **IndexedDB** application, I have used **XMLHttpRequest** to contact my server side method.. After that, I have added the **jquery plugin** to my project and referenced it in my page, now it is showing error as **"Method is not defined"**, If I comment the jquery reference, it is working fine.. But I want to use jquery, how to avoid that error, give me some suggestions..

Comment: What method is not defined?

Comment: my methods containing XMLHttpRequests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put the ajax request inside the jQuery ready callback?

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax ...
});
```

Comment: If I reference the jquery plugin, it is showing error as **"Your Method is not defined"**... Any reason why it is throwing error like that..